# Visual Studio 2015 Randomly Hanging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, freeze, devenv

I am having an issue where my Visual Studio randomly hangs. The issue does not occur during any specific task, but randomly throughout the day.

I have tried renaming %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ folder to VisualStudio.backup\ to rebuild the folder from scratch. Also tried doing a repair.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: report this to Microsoft on connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer in your case but in my case the culprit was the service `VSStandardCollectorService`. I restarted this service without restarting Visual Studio and I was able to use Visual Studio 2015 again.

I found this out by looking in the Task Manager. Find the visual studio process then choose "Go to details" from the context menu. Then choose "Analyze wait chain" from the context menu of the details item. You will see all the stuff it's depending on in terms of wait, for any item that is hung. FYI: When something isn't hung (or waiting), it doesn't give a wait tree. This really takes the mystery out of hangs.